# make textbox axquire fullwidth using flexlayout angular

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMNY8.png)I am new designing with angularflex , I want to make the third field in popup to acquire maxwidth using flexdesigning not with standard css width property ,can anyone help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0j0u.png)

popup works!

{{validationErrors.getError(form.controls['Description'])}} 
                      
                
            
             
                
                    
                    
                        {{validationErrors.getError(form.controls['Description'])}} 
                      
                

            



    
    
    
        
            
                
                
                    {{validationErrors.getError(form.controls['Description'])}} 
                  
            
        


    
        Submit
          Close

Comment: Please share your code so far

Comment: This question could receive a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639697/java-script-map-array-of-objects# if you edit the question and format your code so that it's readable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is not with flex (your container is probably full width), but with the control itself. Its css does not instruct it to take all the available space.

So you have to put `width: 100%` in the css code for your control.

Comment: can you guide me how to design with flex

Comment: Thank you for your valuable explanation,can you share me any  code sample , how to design with flex

Comment: You did all you had to do with flex. Now use CSS on your button.

Comment: tq you for your valuable explanation , how can I master designing in angular flex , can you give me any reference

Comment: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview